# Write float numbers to file with decimal instead of scientific

Tags: delphi

I need to save down some variables to a text file but I don't want them to be saved as scientific values, i.e. 1.0000000E+0 but rather as 1.00. Is there a way to set the format on FormCreate or do I have to format every single variable myself? There are probably around 50 variables that needs to be saved so I'm looking for someway to save time and lines.

```
var
A, B, C, D, E, F, ShapeIndex, X, Y, Z: array of double;

procedure TWriteDerob.Mapping;
 nel := (DerobModel.WallCount + DerobModel.RoofCount + DerobModel.FloorCount);
  SetLength(Name, nel);
  SetLength(A, nel);
  SetLength(B, nel);
  SetLength(C, nel);
  SetLength(D, nel);
  SetLength(E, nel);
  SetLength(F, nel);

  for i := 0 to nel do
  begin
    if (i = 0) or (i = 2) then
    begin
      A[i] := Surface.Width;
      B[i] := Surface.Height;
    end;
    if (i = 1) or (i = 3) then
    begin
      A[i] := Surface.Length;
      B[i] := Surface.Height;
    end;
    if (i = 4) and (i=5) then
    begin
      A[i] := Surface.Width;
      B[i] := Surface.Length;
    end;
  end;

end;
procedure TWriteDerob.Save;
var
  T: TextFile;
  j: integer;
begin

  AssignFile(T, FFilename);
  Rewrite(T);
for j := 0 to nel - 1 do
  begin
    WriteLn(T, '   ', A[j], '   ', B[j], '   ', C[j], '   ', D[j], '   ', E[j],
      '   ', F[j], ' ', Zenith[j], ' ', Azimuth[j], ' ', X[j], '      ', Y[j],
      '      ', Z[j]);
end;
```

This is just a partion of the code that uses the bits that I want to change from scientific values to decimal values if it can help you.

Comment: I don't really think that it would make a difference but I'll edit in some of the code that you can see :) @J...I've edited in some code for you now.

Comment: FWIW, `if (i = 4) and (i=5) then` should probably use `or`, since I can never be 4 and 5 at the same time.

Comment: ...or like e.g. `case i of 0, 2: DoSomething; 1, 3: DoSomethingElse; end;`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the many float to text conversion functions to control this. For example:

```
var
  val: Double;
  str: string;
....
str := Format('%.3f', [val]);
// or as an alternative:
str := FormatFloat('0.000', val);
```

The `FloatToStr()` function, which I guess you are using, does not give you such fine grained control.

Obviously you don't want to write this code over and over again. But that's a standard problem. Use the standard solution of extracting to a procedure.

---

Your question edit supplies more details. Now we know that you use `Writeln` to output to a text file. You can apply formatting with `Writeln`. For instance, for three decimal places use:

```
Writeln(val:0:3);
```

You'll want to consult the documentation for [`Write`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Write).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, apparently I need to always include my code in the future :)

Comment: There's a certain amount of skill required to know when to include code, and when to omit it. Usually if people ask for the code, then it's worth adding it.

Comment: Absolutely, I didn't try to hide my code or anything, just thought that it wouldn't make any big difference but boy was I wrong.

Comment: +1. It's nice when you actually have the requirements when you write your answer. :-)

Comment: @user3464658 It can also be helpful to see the general approach you are taking.  Often what is tedious by one method can be restructured to something more efficient.  By seeing where your code is starting from it makes it easier to suggest improvements or alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to set a numeric format for writing to a text file globally. You'll need to do it yourself.

The easiest way would probably be to write a function that does the formatting, and then a procedure that writes each value to the specified file using that function to format the numbers. That formatting function would simply use `Format('%.3f', [YourVal])` or `FormatFloat('0.00', YourVal);`.

For storing your array, you'd simply loop through them, formatting each individual value and writing it to the file.

You are aware that just simply forcing a format can cause loss of significant digits that can affect calculations, right?

Comment: Yes, but it's simple calculations that'll mostly use 2 or 3 decimals anyway. How do I format an array of doubles, say that I want to format X[0..6] to only 2 decimals?

Comment: In a loop, of course: `for i := 0 to High(MyArrayOfDoubles) do begin str := Format('%.3f', [MyArrayOfDoubles[i]]); { somehow write str to file } end;`

Comment: Note that the doubles themselves are not formatted. They have an internal representation that is always the same. The output is formatted. How they are formatted is up to you. Just loop through the array to write the values in the format you want.